# Non responsive website made using Create React App - Page showing zoomed in on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, viewport, create-react-app

[image]
[image]

Background of the problem - I am creating a simple HTML landing page using create react app node package manager.
I started having problem when I tried to make the website mobile friendly.

Specific problem - 
When I check the `create react app` public folder, I do not see anything wrong with the viewport meta tag and it is as is should be.Here is another screenshot.

[image]

When I open the website on the mobile its zoomed in and the background color is out of proportion. I am guessing it is happening because of viewport meta data not getting rendered correctly.

Anyone with a react and CSS skill combined will be able to figure out what is making this happen. I am attaching a gif of the problem below.

[image]

[link two](https://media.giphy.com/media/5QMIqeb9wfEWnZlkei/giphy.mp4)

I need help with fixing the viewport meta data for a landing page created using Reacts scaffolded 'Create react application'.

I am trying to make the site mobile friendly however am facing the following issue. Kindly load the following link on a mobile device or mobile simulation mode in the browser.

http://sagarmunjal.github.io/learnreactjs

Also, when the page resizes. I would want to learn how to make the text resize/ adjust according to the window being resized.

The code is available at master branch. https://github.com/sagarmunjal/learnreactjs.git

Any solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Also, please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Kindly learn to help. 

There are a lot of lazy people like you creating the gap even bigger and bigger by pointing fingers than even making lil or making no effort at all to read what is written. 

Fire works both ways. it lights up the world and creates brightness. 
It burns down things too.

Comment: That was inspirational bro but the above comment is from StackOverflow's official Docs stating rules on how SO works.

Comment: But how to add more information, when I actually can not add more?
Can you help in telling me how to add more information?
Even if all the emphasis on editing is being done in good will. What use is it bringing to a developer looking for inspiration. Stackoverflow and many other communities have just become a "downvote for downvote" "upvote for upvote" kind of community. The entire crowd who really care so less to read what is written and just hit the downvote button by seeing 'someone else's negative comment'. Where is the use of such editing?
Honestly have you tried solving the prob? NO.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Hero-h1` has a font size of `3.5em` which is making the title stretch outside of the page making it bigger than it should be. This might be a problem with more of your layout.

I suggest you look into media queries if you want to make a responsive website. Here is a good article on the subject: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Here is some more info on how the `em` and `rem` units work: https://css-tricks.com/rem-global-em-local/

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But I am looking for someone who has the technical acumen to solve this particular problem. The internet is rife with knowledge about rems and ems.

Comment: But your particular problem has nothing to do with create-react-app... It is your css code, and I do not think you will find anyone here who is willing to magically solve your problem, especially based on a premise that is flawed.

Comment: I was exactly looking for what you said i wont get. Someone volunteering to help. I know nothing is wrong with create-react-app, that was the context of the question asked.